# Why is Ranajay unable to tell Iman that he loves her?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, kusum-dola

In the TV serial *Kusum Dola* telecasted in Star Jalsha, Ranajay has fallen deeply in love with Iman. But he is unable to tell this to Iman. Iman believes that Ranajay is a very kind man and he is only doing his duty.

So what prevents Ranajay from bringing on the courage to tell Iman how much he loves her?